# ggmap to get travel distance from dataframe

Tags: r, google-maps-api, sf, ggmap

I am trying to use the `mapdist()` function from the `ggmap` package to get travel distances from coordinates in a dataframe.

```
# need an api key to use the ggmap function

register_google(key = "") 

library (tidyverse)
library(ggmaps)
starting_point <- tribble(
  ~row_id, ~X, ~Y,
  1, -119.13968, 50.53766,
  2, -134.26792, 60.45440
)
destination_1 <- tribble( 
  ~row_id, ~X, ~Y,
  1, -119.13968, 50.53766,
  2, -134.26792, 60.45440
)
destination_2 <- tribble(
  ~row_id, ~X, ~Y,
  1, -119.13835, 50.55011,
  2, -135.05166, 60.71958
)
```

I like the output produced here

```
# get coordinates 
(wh <- as.numeric(geocode("white house")))
(lm <- as.numeric(geocode("lincoln memorial washington dc")))
# entering coordinate instead of address
(df <- mapdist(wh, lm, mode = "driving"))
```

I want to get two data frames back, using the `starting_point` as the start and the two destination data sets as the end. The row id gives to specific locations I wish to target.

I've tried entering the coordinates as a list and matrix and still seem to get an error.